# Azure - Identity documents don't returns CountryRegion

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I need to scan data from a passport, and I require the region code field. However, with some passports, it doesn't work, and the region is not displayed. Is there any way to adjust settings to correct this issue?

Here is the code for id scanning

```
export const AzureAnalyzeId = async (Base64: string) => {
  try {
    const initialResponse = await client
      .path(`/documentModels/{modelId}:analyze`, "prebuilt-idDocument")
      .post({
        contentType: "application/json",
        body: {
          base64Source: Base64,
        },
        queryParameters: { locale: "en-IN", features: [] },
      });

    if (isUnexpected(initialResponse)) {
      throw initialResponse.body.error;
    }
    const poller = await getLongRunningPoller(client, initialResponse);
    const analyzeResult = (
      (await poller.pollUntilDone()).body as AnalyzeResultOperationOutput
    ).analyzeResult;

    const documents = analyzeResult?.documents;

    const document = documents && documents[0];

    if (document) {
      if (document.docType === "idDocument.driverLicense") {
        console.log("Extracted a Driver License:");

        return { document, page: analyzeResult.pages };
      } else if (document.docType === "idDocument.passport") {
        console.log("Extracted a Passport:");
        return { document, page: analyzeResult.pages };
      } else {
        console.error("Unknown document type in result:", document);
        return { document, page: analyzeResult.pages };
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error("Expected at least one receipt in the result.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error reading or analyzing document:", error);
  }
};
```

I attempted to loop through the array of lines and check if the content matches the list of region codes, then add it to the final data along with other fields. But this method may not be entirely accurate, so I need something better.

```
for (let key of data.pages.lines) {
       if (countryCodes.includes(key.content.toUpperCase())) {
          data.CountryRegion = {
                content: key.content.toUpperCase(),
          } as any;
           break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below sample that uses the Azure Form Recognizer client library to perform document analysis on a sample Indian passport image.

- Create a single-service or multi-service Document Intelligence resource in the Azure portal.
- Obtain your key and endpoint from the created resource.
- I Followed Document  of Intelligence formerly Form [Recognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/quickstarts/get-started-sdks-rest-api?view=doc-intel-4.0.0&preserve-view=true&pivots=programming-language-javascript).
- Install the required npm packages:
  `npm i @azure-rest/ai-document-intelligence@1.0.0-beta.1`

[`idDocument.passport`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/document-intelligence/concept-id-document?view=doc-intel-4.0.0#iddocumentpassport)

[image]

**Note:**
The CountryRegion field has the countryRegion type, which refers to the issuing country or organization. It is not a fixed type like string, date, or array, etc. Please check if the CountryRegion field exists in the selected URL, or if it is presented differently.

**Azure:**

[image]

**Code:**

```js
const { AzureKeyCredential, DocumentAnalysisClient } = require("@azure/ai-form-recognizer");


const key = "<your-key>";
const endpoint = "<your-endpoint>";

// sample document
const formUrl = "https://sampath1233sa23344545/sampathpujari/sample-indian-passport-1.jpg";

async function main() {
    // create your `DocumentAnalysisClient` instance and `AzureKeyCredential` variable
    const client = new DocumentAnalysisClient(endpoint, new AzureKeyCredential(key));

    const poller = await client.beginAnalyzeDocument("prebuilt-document", formUrl);

    const { keyValuePairs } = await poller.pollUntilDone();

    if (keyValuePairs.length <= 0) {
        console.log("No key-value pairs were extracted from the document.");
    } else {
        console.log("Key-Value Pairs:");
          for (const {
                  key,
                  value,
                  confidence
              } of keyValuePairs) {
            console.log("- Key  :", `"${key.content}"`);
            console.log("  Value:", `"${value?.content ?? "<undefined>"}" (${confidence})`);
        }
    }
}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]